# How to delete first occurrence of value in array?

Tags: c++

I have a container of integers from which I would like to delete a specific value `v`. The container can contain more than one copy of `v` but I only want to delete the first instance I encounter. How do I fix my code to accomplish this?

```
void delete (int s[] , int &top , int v)
{
    int ts[size] ;
    int ttop=-1;
    while(top!=-1)
    {
        if(s[top]!=v)
            push(ts,ttop,s[top]);
        pop(top);
    }
    while(ttop!=-1)
    {
        push(s,top,ts[ttop]);
        pop(ttop);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a flag which will be set after the first find.

```
void delete (int s[] , int &top , int v)
{
    bool found = false;
    int ts[size] ;
    int ttop=-1;
    while(top!=-1)
    {
        if (s[top]!=v)
        {
            push(ts,ttop,s[top]);
        }
        else
        {
           if (found == false)
           {
              found = true;
              push(ts,ttop,s[top]);
           }
        }
        pop(top);
    }
    while(ttop!=-1)
    {
        push(s,top,ts[ttop]);
        pop(ttop);
    }
}
```

As long as `found` is false, it will also check to see if the element matches. Once `found` is true, it will always include the item, even if it matches.

Note that this is not the most effective way to do this, merely a means of modifying your code so that it does the trick.

Comment: i want to delete one value each time , not the all same value  .

Comment: @M.ALi Sorry about that. It should be correct now.